# Proof of the product of two primitive polynomials is primitive question.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

My question concerns the bolded line in this excerpt of the proof from the book I'm reading:

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be primitive polynomials, and suppose that
$f(x)g(x)$ is not primitive. Let $p$ be a prime divisor of the content of
$f(x)g(x)$, and let $f'(x), g'(x)$ and $[f(x)g(x)]'$ be the polynomials obtained
from $f(x), g(x)$, and $f(x)g(x)$ by reducing the coefficients modulo $p$.
**Then $f'(x)$ and $g'(x)$ and belong to the integral domain $\Bbb Z_p[x]$ and $f'(x)g'(x) = [f(x)g(x)]' = 0$**

Why does $[f(x)g(x)]' = 0$?

Comment: because each coefficient of $fg$ is a multiple of $p$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen So if $c_i$ are the coefficients of $fg$, then it boils down to $p | $ content$(fg) = gcd(c_1, c_2, ..., c_n) \Rightarrow p | c_1, c_2, ...,$ and $c_n$?

Comment: @OliverG But surely this is true, since it is infact just a definition.